# How to make QComboBox that has only one field editable?

Tags: qt, qcombobox, eventfilter

I want to make a `QComboBox` that allows you to select value or enter your own value. It should work so that if you select the editable option and enter text, that will be the text for that option. If you select other and then go back to editable one, the text you've entered should persist.

I already made some progress. It looks like this:

#### The combobox menu

[image: image description]

#### Editable item selected

[image: image description]

#### Normal item selected

[image: image description]

I achieved this using event filter:

```
class MagicComboBoxEventFilter : public QObject {
public:
    explicit MagicComboBoxEventFilter(QObject* parent=0) : 
          QObject(parent),
          parentBox(nullptr),
          lastValue(""),
          editableIndex(-1)
    {
        parentBox = dynamic_cast<QComboBox*>(parent);
        if(parentBox) {
            connect(parentBox, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
                this, &MagicComboBoxEventFilter::currentIndexChanged);
    }
public slots:
        void currentIndexChanged(int index) {
            // Item data entry is unused, so I used it to determine
            // the editable field from others
            bool editable = parentBox->itemData(index).toInt()==666;
            parentBox->setEditable(editable);
        }
private:
    QComboBox* parentBox;
};
```

This is applied to new combobox:

```
QComboBox* comboBox = new QComboBox(this);
comboBox->setEditable(false);
new MagicComboBoxEventFilter(comboBox);
```

The problem I am facing is how to persist the editable value even if user selects other items. I tried to hook up on editable text change event, this is my enhanced event filter. I will not repeat the whole class code, only other thing is there's additional `connect` call in constructor now:

```
public slots:
        void currentIndexChanged(int index) {
            bool editable = parentBox->itemData(index).toInt()==666;
            parentBox->setEditable(editable);

            // If editable field selected, restore the last value entered
            if(editable) {
                parentBox->setItemText(index, lastValue);
            }
        }
        // slot connected in constructor
        void editTextChanged(const QString& text) {
            lastValue = text;
        }
private:
    QComboBox* parentBox;
    // Last string value the editable field had
    // qt doesn't remember that
    QString lastValue;
```

The problem is that when user selects other item **editTextChanged fires before currentIndexChanged** and I end up having the selected item's text in `lastValue`, not the last entered text.

How to go around that? I really tried hard and I need some help.

Comment: Maybe by getting the children of the QComboBox, which is a QStandardItemModel, and install another event filter on this one? I don't have time to test your code but the answer to this question might interest me

Answer (score 2):

Umm, I wanted the same thing, but I think it was quite easy (sorry, python syntax):

```
class EditableComboBox(QComboBox):

    def __init__(self):
        QComboBox.__init__(self)
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.fix)
        self.setInsertPolicy(QComboBox.InsertAtCurrent)

    def fix(self, index):
        if (self.currentData() == '----'):
            self.setEditable(True)
        else:
            self.setEditable(False)
```

Basically, just set `insertPolicy` to `InsertAtCurrent` and react to every `currentIndexChanged` by setting the `editable` property. I used `----` as a marker for the editable field, and set the items:

```
cb = EditableComboBox()
cb.addItem('', '----')
cb.addItem('One', '1')
cb.addItem('Two', '2')
cb.addItem('Three', '3')
```

PS. When you change the text, you have to press enter for it to stick, otherwise if you select another item the text will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. My scenario was choosing a file extension.

```
void VideoFormatWidget::on_comboBox_FileExtension_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    ui->comboBox_FileExtension->setEditable(index==1);
}
```

I had entry

```
0 "Select File Extension"
```

and entry

```
1 "---"
```

set up Qt Creator

and some software added items too.

```
ui->comboBox_FileExtension->addItem("avi");
ui->comboBox_FileExtension->addItem("mjpg");
ui->comboBox_FileExtension->addItem("mpg");
ui->comboBox_FileExtension->addItem("m2v");
ui->comboBox_FileExtension->addItem("m4v");
ui->comboBox_FileExtension->addItem("wmv");
```